# How should i get the view which we usually see on Action item button click in Photo app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, photo

I want to include an action button on click of which i want to display the exact same view which we get in Photo application which has options like Email Photo, MMS, and other sharing options with Cancel button.

This view is transparent also.

Please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [UIActionSheet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Also, see the given sample applications there.